# Query to count employees and display departments that have more than one employee

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core

I need query to display all departments, their locations and number of employees, where number of Employees is >1, using LINQ.

I have  ICollection property in the Department model.

Department table:

```
departmentId | departmentLocation
      1             London
      2             Paris
      3             New York
```

Employee table:

```
employeeId | employeeName |departmentId
      1           John         3
      2           Mary         2
      3           Steve        3
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }` property in the `Department` model then:

```
var result = context
                .Department
                .Where(d => d.Employees.Count > 1)
                .Select(d => new
            {
                d.departmentId,
                d.departmentLocation,
                NumberOfEmployees = d.Employees.Count
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a million, it works, but gives me all Departments, now I will try to get only those where employee number is mor than 1.

Comment: Glad it helped, did you try the updated answer? I added `Where` method in the updated answer.

Comment: I have tried on my own and added "Where(d=> d.NumberOfEmployees>1)" at the end, but your solution looks better.